# How to optimize elasticsearch's full text search to match strings like 'C++'

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

We have a search engine for text content which contains strings like `c++` or `c#`. The switch to Elasticsearch has shown that the search does not match on terms like 'c++'. `++` is removed.

How can we teach elasticsearch to match correctly in a full text search and not to remove special characters? Characters like comma `,` should of course still be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own [custom-analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) which generates token as per your requirement, for your example I created a below custom analyzer with a text field name `language` and indexed some sample docs:

### Index creation with a custom analyzer

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "replace_comma"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "replace_comma": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        ", => \\u0020"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "language": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tokens generated for text like `c++`, `c#` and `c,java`.

POST http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index}}/_analyze

```
{
  "text" : "c#",
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "c#",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 2,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

for `c,java` it generated 2 separate tokens `c` and `java` as it replaces `,` with whitespace shown below:

```
{
  "text" : "c, java",
  "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "c",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 1,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "java",
            "start_offset": 3,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: You need to understand the [analysis process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and accordingly modify your custom-analyzer to make it work for all of your use-case, My example might not work for all your edge cases, But hope you get an idea on how to handle such requirements.

Comment: To me this looks like that it is necessary to configure every special "string feature" manually. Is that the only way?